# Cast BoxedUnit to scala tuple

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hello everybody i have an error during running my spark scala code . 
it says 
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit cannot be cast to scala.Tuple4

during the saving step wen i try to cast datasets

```
val datasets = Try(Computing.process(input_bi.asInstanceOf[(Dataset[SortieFondsct], Dataset[SortieFondIP], Dataset[EntreeFondsct], Dataset[EntreeFondIP])], connector)) match {
      case Success(v) => System.out.println("Success")
      case Failure(err) => {
        val monitoringToSave = err match {
          case _: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException => Logger.error(ERROR_TYPE_MISSING_ARGS, "Computing", DRIVER_VIR_SORT_NAME, err, true, idDimTemps)
          case _: AnalysisException => Logger.error(ERROR_TYPE_INVALID_QUERY, "Computing", DRIVER_VIR_SORT_NAME, err, true, idDimTemps)
          case _: FileNotFoundException => Logger.error(ERROR_TYPE_FILE_NOT_FOUND, "Computing", DRIVER_VIR_SORT_NAME, err, true, idDimTemps)
          case _: EmptyFileException => Logger.error(ERROR_TYPE_FILE_IS_EMPTY, "Computing", DRIVER_VIR_SORT_NAME, err, true, idDimTemps)
          case _: EmptyColumnException => Logger.error(ERROR_TYPE_COLUMN_VALUE_EMPTY, "Computing", DRIVER_VIR_SORT_NAME, err, true, idDimTemps)
          case _: Throwable => Logger.error(ERROR_UNKNOWN, "Computing", DRIVER_VIR_SORT_NAME, err, true, idDimTemps)
        }
        CassandraClient.saveMonitoring(monitoringToSave, connector)
        throw err
      }
    }





    // ******************** SAVING STEP ********************
    val persist = Try(Saving.process(datasets.asInstanceOf[(Dataset[SortieFondsct], Dataset[SortieFondIP], Dataset[EntreeFondsct], Dataset[EntreeFondIP])])) match { //error here
      case Success(v) => System.out.println("Success")
      case Failure(err) => {
        val monitoringToSave = err match {
          case _: DifferentNumberInsertedLinesException => Logger.error(ERROR_TYPE_DIFF_NB_LINES_INSERT, "Saving", DRIVER_VIR_SORT_NAME, err, true, idDimTemps)
          case _: CannotGetDataFromCassandra => Logger.error(ERROR_TYPE_CANNOT_GET_DATA_FROM_DB, "Saving", DRIVER_VIR_SORT_NAME, err, true, idDimTemps)
          case _: Throwable => Logger.error(ERROR_UNKNOWN, "Saving", DRIVER_VIR_SORT_NAME, err, true, idDimTemps)
        }
        CassandraClient.saveMonitoring(monitoringToSave, connector)
        throw err
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your `dataset` is a **Unit** not a **Dataset**. Maybe you wanted to `case Success(v) => System.out.println("Success"); v` to return the value again. Also, please try to avoid `asInstanceOf` you are basically turning the compiler off.

Comment: Yesss thank you very much. Can you please explain morr about asInstanceOf?